# Arduino Nano Clone Unknown device

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

just bought 2 Arduino Nano clones.

They are using CH340G to communicate over usb.

Issue is that one device is showing up in Device manager (win7 x64) as com port 26 with CH340G driver and all works fine.

Other one is showing as Unknown device.

Is it possible that some firmware on the Atmega itself is missing or device is not working at the hardware level?

Does CH340G needs some form of firmware inside ATMEGA328 to work properly?

PS:

Just tested programming of not working one with USBAsp from ArduinoIDE and it works without any problems, so it seems that maybe usb chip is faulty :?

Comment: The CH340 chip recognision from the pc is  irrelevant with the AVR. If the chip is not shown in the device manager then there is probably something wrong with the hardware. Inspect the PCB, maybe there is a badly soldered joint.

Answer (score 1):

You need a special driver for this adapter, downloadable from the vendor's site. See discussion [here](http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?13,440242)

Comment: As I explained, I bought 2 and one is working without any issue. It reckognizes device and registers CH340G driver without any problem

Comment: Still you might want to try and install the device driver for the non-recognized device. If it won't help, the device is most likely faulty (you have two identical ones, one is working, one is not..)